Can Deno Fresh serve HTML files inside the routes folder?
I put test.html in the routes folder, but both localhost:8000/test and localhost:8000/test.html redirect me to the 404 page. The documentation Routing | Fresh docs doesn't discuss about this.
Or is it that I must use JS/TS files for routing? My solution so far is to put the file on static, then inject it to routes/test.tsx:
export default async function Home() {
  const html = await Deno.readTextFile('./static/test.html') 
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
    />
  );
}

As you can see on the attribute name, this practice is dangerous.

Found a file server on Google: https://medium.com/deno-the-complete-reference/a-beginners-guide-to-building-a-static-file-server-in-deno-a4d12745d233

You could try creating a custom route handler that serves the HTML file
